# CSS selector to select a child in the parent's hierarchy

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using css selectors I want to set the background of the button as red if it is the only button present in the hierarchy of `.parent` class.

I tried the below selector but it fails if the sibling of the button is inside a div.

```
<style> 
.parent  .test:only-of-type {
    background: red;
}
</style>
```

**Case1: no button should be marked red** (selector fails in this case)

```
 <div class="parent">
      <div class="boat">
        <button class="test">This is a paragraph.</button>
      </div>
      <button class="test">This is a paragraph.</button>
     <button class="test">This is a paragraph.</button>
      <div class="other">
        <button class="test">This is a paragraph.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Case2: button should be marked red**

```
 <div class="parent">
      <div class="boat">
        <button class="test">This is a paragraph.</button>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Case3: no button should be marked red**  (selector fails in this case)

```
 <div class="parent">
      <div class="boat">
        <button class="test">This is a paragraph.</button>
      </div>
      <div class="other">
        <button class="test">This is a paragraph.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you try  ?

.parent  .test > button{
    background: red;
}

Comment: Check my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `:only-child` selector:

```css
.parent > .boat:only-child > .test:only-child,
.parent > .test:only-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="boat">
    <button class="test">not red.</button>
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    <button class="test">not red.</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="boat">
    <button class="test">not red.</button>
  </div>
  <button class="test">not red.</button>
  <button class="test">not red.</button>
  <div class="other">
    <button class="test">not red.</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="boat">
    <button class="test">red.</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Selector explained:

- `.parent` - start with your parent
- `> .boat:only-child` greater than (`>`) means direct child so this means that `.boat` has to be a direct child of `.parent` and the only child (this is the `:only-child` bit)
- `> .test:only-child` again this means that `.test` has to be a direct child of `.boat` and the only child

The second selector is optional - in case you just have a button without the boat div

[More info on only-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child)

[More info on direct child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

To get the button red inside of the boat div you can use the selector:

```
.parent > .boat > .test {
}
```